# C++ Calculate bus daily profit (minor mistakes?)

Tags: c++, string, char

There is a certain programming exercise I'm trying to solve in C++(I'm new to it). The exercise requires to calculate the daily profit of buses (public transport) and print the name of the bus which made highest profit and also the sum of its daily profit and also the total profit made by all buses. However, the tickets have different types (1,2,3,4,5 or 6) according to the passengers: 1 is full and full=3, 2 is for teachers=25.5, 3 is for students=22.10 and 4,5,6 are free.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, j; 
    double full_ticket=0, teacher_ticket=0, std_ticket=0, foreign_ticket=0, polis_card=0, elderly_card=0; //declare tickets
    char ticket, c; 
    string bus, hBus; //declare strings for bus names
    double  fuel_amount, fuel_price, daily_profit,busProfit, hAmount, total_amount; 

    cin>>n>>fuel_price; 
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++) 
    {
        cin>>bus>>fuel_amount; //read string and amount of fuel consumed
        do
        {
            cin>>ticket>>c;  //read ticket type and c is comma, after each ticket there **needs** to be a comma
            if(ticket=='1')   
            {
                full_ticket=full_ticket+30;                 
                total_amount=total_amount+full_ticket;
            }
            if(ticket=='2')
            {
                teacher_ticket=teacher_ticket+25.5;             
                total_amount=total_amount+teacher_ticket;
            }
            if(ticket=='3')
            {
                std_ticket=std_ticket+22.10;                     
                total_amount=total_amount+std_ticket;
            }
            if(ticket=='4')
            {
                foreign_ticket=foreign_ticket+0;                    
                total_amount=total_amount+foreign_ticket;
            }
            if(ticket=='5')
            {
                polis_card=polis_card+0;                         
                total_amount=total_amount+polis_card;
            }
            if(ticket=='6')
            {
                elderly_card=elderly_card+0;                    
                total_amount=total_amount+elderly_card;
            }
        }while(c!=';'); //termination of do-while loop when it reads a semicolon


                    //calculate sum per each bus
        busProfit=(full_ticket+teacher_ticket+std_ticket+foreign_ticket+polis_card+elderly_card)-(fuel_amount*fuel_price);

        daily_profit=daily_profit+busProfit; //calculate daily profit of buses

        if(busProfit>hAmount) //set condition for highest bus
        {
            hAmount=busProfit;            
            hBus=bus;
        }


        full_ticket=0; teacher_ticket=0; std_ticket=0; foreign_ticket=0;polis_card=0;elderly_card=0;
        //set variables to 0 before loop starts again

    }

            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);       
            cout<<hBus<<" "<<hAmount<<endl;         //print highest bus and highest amount
            cout<<daily_profit;                     //print daily profit

    return 0;

}
```

This code seems to pass all elementary tests, however there's something wrong with it since it has not been accepted. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could help me find the mistakes.

Comment: We would greatly appreciate if you could use a debugger on your code.  Execute each statement one at a time and watch variable values.  Please edit your post indicating which statement is causing the issue and why.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews is correct, a debugger will point out a certain line of the code that is causing a problem. Run the debugger and post the line that's causing the problems.

Comment: A `switch` statement may be more readable than the multiple `if` statements.

Comment: BTW, you can eliminate the statements that add 0.  Adding 0 to a value does not alter the value; they are of no value to the program.

Comment: Also, why is your code so clustered? Let it breathe.

Comment: Also, `string.h` is for C-style strings and `#include <string>` is for the C++ `std::string` type.

Comment: I wasn't sure what was the problem and since it passed some tests I never thought about debugging it. I did it however and found multiple problems so thank you for suggesting it! I'm not used yet with using switch but I'll give it a try. I know about the values that add 0 but were entered as it was somehow required in the exercise. Thank you for pointing out the library! Changed it immediately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems, although the second may not be relevant because I see no use of `total_amount` beyond the calculations:

`daily_profit` is never initialized before being used.

Your value for `total_amount` is going to be incorrect do to the following:

```
   if(ticket=='1')   
    {
        full_ticket=full_ticket+30;                 
        total_amount=total_amount+full_ticket;
    }
```

In the above code, you are adding the cost of a `full_ticket` to what I assume is your running total of money made from selling full tickets. You then add that value to the `total_amount`. The problem is, you really only want to add 30 to `total_amount` as you are counting the value of EVERY ticket sold each time you add rather than the value of one ticket.

First ticket: `full_ticket = 30, total_amount = 30`
Second ticket: `full_ticket = 60, total_amount = 90`
Third ticket: `full_ticket = 90, total_amount = 180`

This pattern repeats for other ticket prices.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful thank you very much! I made the necessary changes. Hopeful it'll get accepted.